# Add metadata to every video frame with GStreamer and save whole video

Tags: video-streaming, metadata, gstreamer, nvidia, video-processing

I have a pipeline as below in C++;

```
    GstElement* pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("video_pipeline");
    GstElement* videoSrc = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "video_source");
    GstElement* decoder = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decoder");
    GstElement* nvvideoconvert = gst_element_factory_make("nvvideoconvert", "nvidiaconverter");
    GstElement* videoConvert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "convert");
    GstElement* videoScale = gst_element_factory_make("videoscale", "video_scale");
    GstElement* videoFilter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter");
    GstElement* encoder = gst_element_factory_make("vp8enc", "encoder");
    GstElement* mux = gst_element_factory_make("avimux", "muxer");
    GstElement* videoSink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", "video_sink");
```

We want to add and read metadata(i.e. frame number for every frame) with "GstMeta", "gst_buffer_add_meta", "gst_buffer_get_meta" functions. Saved video must be this metadata(frame number).

We can add metadata to buffer and also read metadata but we cannot save video with metadata. We rescreach this problem but "gst_buffer_add_meta" function add metadata only in buffer not video file.

How can i save video with metadata for every frame?

Thanks in advance!